# Java -Xnoclassgc

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a Question concerning the java option -XnoclassGC. It prevents java from runnning the GC.
I´m guessing the responsetime can be shorter because there are no "stop-the-world-pauses". But if you use the concurrent GC, it´s responsetime is good enough for responsetime cruicial aplications, so i´ve read.
Wouldnt it hurt the performance if the heap is never cleaned? 
Does it only prevent the collection of classes?

What´s the use of this option?

(I know you normally shouldnt use it because you could easily get a *OutOfMemoryError* error.)
[http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Xnoclassgc.html?cp=SSYKE2_7.0.0%2F5-8-0-3-24&lang=en]

Answer (score 2):

It disables the GC of classes from PermGen. It doesn't disable the whole GC.

With Java 8, the whole thing is [a bit different](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Java-PERMGEN-Removed) since the PermGen is no longer a part of the Java Heap.

After digging around, I found [this post](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-use/2013-May/001542.html) where it was used to prevent long pauses on Java 6, so I suppose it could have a use in very specific cases (for example where a program keeps loading and unloading the same classes). However, I would start solving the problem from a different angle before resorting to -Xnoclassgc.

Comment: According to the link "Enabling this option is not recommended except under the direction of the IBM support team" so probably only they know :-)

Comment: Ok but the GC cleans the heap. Arent just classes (objects) stored in the heap? What is stored there that hast to be collected?

Comment: @javaBeginner Before Java 8 classes were stored in a special part called the `PermGen`, and this caused a lot of problems. These days things are different.. let me just edit the answer...